# Merging multiple camera streams on Android using libuvc

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera, uvc

I can connect two USB connected cams and view them side by side on screen (thanks to [this example](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera/tree/master/usbCameraTest7). However I want to go a step further - taking two frames from both the videos and stitch them and display.

I have independently done the stitching as well using OpenCV for Android. However I am not sure how can I pick up frames and can create a single stream to display on single surface?

Any pointer appreciated. I hope my question is not too broad. Please suggest edit before downvote :)

thanks